# can't use the index in subscript

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

I don't know why I can't use the index in subscript to retrieve an object in an array.

I got this error:

Argument type '@lvalue MPMediaItem' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'

```
extension Array where Element == MPMediaItem {
    mutating func alignToProb(songIDWithNumberOfPick: [Int: Int]){
        let sortedDict = songIDWithNumberOfPick.sorted{ $0.value > $1.value }
        var result = [MPMediaItem]()
        for (songID, numberOfPick) in sortedDict {
            if let index = self.index(where: { $0.songID == songID }) {
                result += self[index] // this line I got error. // Argument type '@lvalue MPMediaItem' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'
            }
        }
        self = result
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is songID property  declared?

Comment: I declared in extension

Comment: Consider that the result of sorting a dictionary is an array of tuples. `songID` is the iteration index rather than the key of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 result += self[index]
```

does not compile because `+=` appends a *sequence of elements* to an
array (such as another array). To append a single element, use

```
 result.append(self[index])
```

*Remark:* A more compact implementation of your method would be (untested!)

```
extension Array where Element == MPMediaItem {
    mutating func alignToProb(songIDWithNumberOfPick: [Int: Int]){
        let sortedIDs = songIDWithNumberOfPick.sorted{ $0.value > $1.value }.map { $0.key }
        let result = sortedIDs.flatMap { songID in
            first(where: { $0.songID == songID })
        }
        self = result
    }
}
```